# View Service extensibility in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

Like in IdentityServer3, is it possible to have HTML views (AngularApp) in IdentityServer4? Is there any documentation about this?

Like this: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomViewService

I'm using IS3 with custom views and custom user store (my app database) but I need to port it to .NET Core using IS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IS4 you are in total control over the views and the technology you like to build them. Check our samples - they use plain MVC controllers and actions.

Comment: Thanks Dominick! I have carefully read the annoucing post on your blog and understood. In IS4 I only need to put my controllers and actions on the correct route (e.g. ui/login) and after all, use the SignInInteraction service to notify IS4 that the login successfully occurred, right?

Comment: @DiogoDamiani Can you show a link to the post? Trying to implement this and no luck so far. Thanks

Comment: @yosbel In IS4 you have total control of views. You can see in Host project sample: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/dev/src/Host/Views. That is the link to the post: https://leastprivilege.com/2016/01/11/announcing-identityserver-for-asp-net-5-and-net-core/

Comment: The above command by Diogo Damiani is a bad link.  Is there an update?

Comment: @JoelPalmer you can find from here, https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/src/IdentityServer4/host/Views